# How to use Viewbinding in Android Java ListView

Tags: java, android

how to use view binding in android list view?
I know how to use it in Recycler View, but don't know how to use it in list view

Comment: why even use a listview then ?

Comment: that's probably not an answer

Comment: well, i didn't write it as an answer, i wrote it as a comment :) and i'm asking because list views are deprecated so why bother learning how to do it

Comment: @a_local_nobody only use case for list view that I'm aware of is that they're supported by [`RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews)

Comment: @Pawel and i think widgets, perhaps ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody you're right, since its an old app and listviews are used in it so, I don't want to waste my time shifting it to recycler view, that's why i need some idea to use view binding in listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since list view provides raw views instead of viewholders you have to use another way to hold viewbinding, for example you can use view tags.

Create new ID in any of your resource files (like `values.xml`):

```
<id name="viewBinding" />
```

Then spawn view binding in your adapter (modified sample from [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView)):

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      // override other abstract methods here

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
          ItemViewBinding binding;
          if (convertView == null) {
              binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);
              convertView = binding.getRoot();
              convertView.setTag(R.id.viewBinding, binding);
          } else {
              binding = ((ItemViewBinding ) convertView.getTag(R.id.viewBinding));
          }
          
          binding.getText1().setText(getItem(position));

          return convertView;
      }
  }
```